# Using JQuery to disable RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using JQuery to hide/show a div depending on the selected value of a combo box. This part works fine. However, when hiding the div, the jquery function should also disable 3 RequiredFieldValidators which are in that div. I've been looking online and it seems that this can easily be accomplished using:

```
ValidatorEnable(ValidatorName, false);
```

But when I try using that method, nothing works, the RequiredFieldValidators still display an error even though the div is hidden.

My JQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var det = $("#SponsorDetails");
            $(det).hide();
            var all = $("#AllDetails");
            $(all).hide();

            $("#<%=SelectAccount.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                //hide social worker and sponsor stuff
                var value = $("#<%=SelectAccount.ClientID %> option:selected").val();
                if (value == "Social_Worker") {
                    //show social worker stuff
                    $("#AllDetails").show("slow");
                    $("#SponsorDetails").hide("slow");
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=AddressValidator.ClientID %>"), false);
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=CityValidator.ClientID %>"), false);
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=CountryValidator.ClientID %>"), false);

                } else if (value == "Sponsor") {
                    //show sponsor stuff
                    $("#AllDetails").show("slow");
                    $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=AddressValidator.ClientID %>"), true);
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=CityValidator.ClientID %>"), true);
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%=CountryValidator.ClientID %>"), true);

                }
            });

        });


    </script>
```

Someone suggested I could use Validation groups or a custom validator, but using jquery just seems much simpler but I don't know why it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have confuze the jQuery with the simple javascript. In simple javascript we do not use the symbol `#` in front of the element id. So remove it from all the **getElementById** function and it will work.

For example

```
document.getElementById("<%=CountryValidator.ClientID %>")
```

The error you get is because you call `getElementById` with out check the return of them, so you get throw error from the use of the return of this function that can not be use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to enable validator manually for run again...use in Jquery

```
  ValidatorEnable($("[id$='RegularExpressionValidator4']")[0], true);
```

Comment: Please provide more details about answer you have written. It will help others to understand it clearly